# Is there a module that will allow me to pair a bluetooth keyboard to an arduino?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to pair a bluetooth keyboard to an arduino project, so that pressing a key on the keyboard causes an action to happen on the Arduino. Let's say that pressing Q on the keyboard makes an LED turn on, and pressing W makes it turn off.

I know that I need some sort of bluetooth module connected to the Arduino, and I need to pair the keyboard to the module. I also know that it must be a module that can act in Master mode and use the HID protocol. But I cannot find a module that does what I want. For example, the HC05 module cannot do HID.

Has anyone done this? Can you tell me which module you used please? I don't want to involve anything else, just an Arduino, a module, and a bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: I googled "arduino bluetooth hid host" https://www.circuitsathome.com/mcu/arduino/bluetooth-hid-devices-now-supported-by-the-usb-host-library/

Comment: I also looking for a module that could act as a master and support HID!